# use join count in calculation in select

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

```
SELECT e.qty * e.unit_cost * e.unit_no * (e.factor/100) AS Ext_price, c.cost_type, c.cost_dt, c.internal_cost_amt, c.client_cost_amt
FROM equipment e
LEFT JOIN CostAllocation c ON (c.object_row_id = e.row_id)
```

I now want to divide the `Ext_price` by the number of `CostAllocation` rows that match the equipment row.  How would I do that?

Comment: can you just return `COUNT(c.object_row_id)` with this `select` and do it on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.qty*e.unit_cost*e.unit_no*e.factor/(100*x.cnt) AS Ext_price,
       c.cost_type,
       c.cost_dt,
       c.internal_cost_amt,
       c.client_cost_amt
FROM equipment e
LEFT JOIN CostAllocation c ON c.object_row_id = e.row_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT row_id,
          count(*) cnt
   FROM CostAllocation
   GROUP BY row_id) x ON c.object_row_id = x.row_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try below:

```
select  g.*,g.Ext_price/(select count(*) from CostAllocation k where k.object_row_id=g.row_id) as youranswer
from 
(
SELECT e.row_id,e.qty*e.unit_cost*e.unit_no*e.factor/100 AS Ext_price, c.cost_type, c.cost_dt, c.internal_cost_amt, c.client_cost_amt
FROM equipment e
LEFT JOIN CostAllocation c ON c.object_row_id = e.row_id)g
```

Answer (score 0):

Since mysql does not support analytical functions it is probably easiest to add a subquery (untested):

```
SELECT Ext_price, cost_type, cost_dt, internal_cost_amt
     , client_cost_amt
     , Ext_price / ( nullif( (select count(1) 
                              from CostAllocation c2
                              where c2.object_row_id = e.row_id), 0) )
FROM (
    SELECT e.qty*e.unit_cost*e.unit_no*e.factor/100 AS Ext_price
         , c.cost_type, c.cost_dt, c.internal_cost_amt, c.client_cost_amt
    FROM equipment e
    LEFT JOIN CostAllocation c 
        ON c.object_row_id = e.row_id
) as T
```

I added nullif to avoid division by zero.